# Remove accent from enumi when using xelatex

Tags: xetex, enumitem

The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setmainfont{GFSArtemisia}[
Scale=1.05,
Extension = .otf,
UprightFont = *,
ItalicFont = *It,
BoldFont = *Bold,
BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt]
\usepackage{eulervm}

\begin{document} 

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item Να δείξετε ότι $\lambda=2$ και στη συνέχεια να υπολογίσετε τα όρια $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \left[ (x^2-1) f(x) \right]$,  $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^+} f(x)$.
    
    \item Να δείξετε ότι η $f$ αντιστρέφεται και στην συνέχεια να δείξετε ότι $f^{-1}=f$. 
    
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

produces enumeration like this (α'). Is it possible to overwrite the label so that the produced enumeration  is like (α)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can neutralize the working of `\anw@print` and related macros. Beware that large numerals will still sport the prefix `͵` U+0375 GREEK LOWER NUMERAL SIGN. In order to remove also this one, deep surgery would be needed.

Don't load `xltxtra`. It used to be recommended several years ago, but nowadays it isn't.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}% Don't load it
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setmainlanguage{greek}

\setmainfont{GFSArtemisia}[
  Scale=1.05,
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *,
  ItalicFont = *It,
  BoldFont = *Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt
]
\usepackage{eulervm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\anw@print}{}
\renewcommand{\anw@true}{}
\renewcommand{\anw@false}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item Να δείξετε ότι $\lambda=2$ και στη συνέχεια να υπολογίσετε τα όρια $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \left[ (x^2-1) f(x) \right]$,  $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^+} f(x)$.
    
    \item Να δείξετε ότι η $f$ αντιστρέφεται και στην συνέχεια να δείξετε ότι $f^{-1}=f$. 
    
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks both for the answer and the tip. Why not use `xltxtra`? Basically, what does it do?

Comment: @Tolaso Well, you should *never* load a package without knowing why. Anyway, it's basically a wrapper for loading `fontspec`, `metalogo` and `realscripts`. You probably don't need `metalogo` and you almost surely don't want `realscripts`.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about... but thanks! Package removed as suggested!!